# Html5 geolocation in google maps api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to make a google maps center on someones location when the press a button using html5 geolocation. But i dont know how it works and i have too many other things to focus on so it would be really nice if someone could tell me.

Comment: I wouldn't want to waste your precious time reading my answer when you don't have any time. Counter proposal, will you write my answer? cause i don't have the time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example from google

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Comment: Thanks for the link but now it says "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and dose not work. The code i have is `function initialize() {
   if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);
    }
    
    var mapOptions = {
     center: pos, //new google.maps.LatLng(51.762841,-2.2454),
     zoom: 6,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
     
    };)}
`

Comment: I can't work with this, I'm sorry. You can always hire people to do it for you...

Comment: thanks a lot anyway you pointed me in the right direction